# Why my logs are not written to the file?

Tags: java, logging

I'm trying write my logs in file, but file is empty and logs print in console. File is placed in `resource` folder project. Why is problem?

```
import java.util.logging.FileHandler;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter;

private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class.getName());
private FileHandler fileHandler;

public String book(){
        try {
            fileHandler = new FileHandler("super.txt", 100000, 1, true);
            SimpleFormatter formatter = new SimpleFormatter();
            fileHandler.setFormatter(formatter);
            logger.addHandler(fileHandler);
            logger.setLevel(Level.INFO);
            logger.log(Level.INFO, "INFO");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        logger.log(Level.WARNING, "WARN");
        return "log is save or not )";
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code and it works. It creates a log file in the "current directory" that is the project root directory. You can pass a calculated absolute path as file name to get it logging where you want.

Logging to console can be disabled by adding this :

```
logger.setUseParentHandlers(false);
```

Comment: When i added `logger.setUseParentHandlers(false);` loggin in console disabled. But file is empty. It may be a problem in Ubuntu?

Comment: I tried that in Ubuntu. I think this a path problem. Try to pass an absolute path just for test. ex : /home/[your_user_name]/super.txt and then check your personal folder.

Comment: I set path `fileHandler = new FileHandler("/home/[my name]/Workspace/[my project]/super.txt", 100000, 1, true);` and log is write! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with "resource/super.txt" instead of "super.txt" ? 
Also, don't forget to close your fileHandler when you have finished with it.

Comment: If I set `resource/super.txt` my IDE not found file, but if set `super.txt` is correctly.

Comment: Ok ok, I saw after you answered that maybe it's because you didn't called close() on your fileHandler when finished with it ?

Comment: I added `fileHandler.flush();` and `fileHandler.close();` and this not solve problem

Comment: Even if a file is not recorded, why `log` is displayed in the console?